# Аутентификация ASP.NET с ролями из внешней БД

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webforms, аутентификация, auth

Доброго времени суток. В процессе разработки веб-приложения на `ASP.NET WebForms` по велению заказчика в БД (`MS SQL`) ввели `RoleMask` для юзеров. Соответственно, необходимо разграничить доступ к разным формам по этой самой `RoleMask`. С аутентификацией я до этого не работал, в голову сразу лезет глупая идея записать юзера в холдер и проверять в каждом `Page_Load`, есть ли у юзера права. Недостатки идеи очевидны. Копая эту тему, наткнулся на `FormsAuthefication`, и вроде бы все неплохо. Доступ настраивается в `web.config` как-то так:

```
<location path="path"> 
   <system.web>
      <authorization> 
         <allow roles="role"/>
         <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

Как добавить свои роли? `Roles.CreateRole` валится (ProviderException - Функция диспетчера ролей не включена).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делать в `Page_Load` - идея не удачная. Надо включить использование ролей.
Можете воспользоваться [средством администрирования веб-сайта ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms228053%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), [еще ссылка](http://aspnet-web.ru/voprosy-bezopasnosti-aspnet-prilozhenij/ispolzovanie-instrumenta-aspnet-site-administration.html). 
Для этого, `Меню Проект` (точно не помню, если не там, посмотрите в других пунктах меню) -> Конфигурация `Asp.Net` - откроется панель конфигурации вашего приложения (при этом, естественно, `web.config` должен быть настроен на нужную БД пользователей). 
В этой панели можно управлять пользователями, а также ролями и некоторыми другими настройками. Нужно найти настройки ролей и просто включить их. Можно также, добавлять/удалять роли, настраивать доступ к разным директориям приложения (можно в ручную делать, как вы описали) и т.д. Для каждого БД настройки нужно производить отдельно (для тестовых и рабочих).
Настройки описаны для стандартного поставщика пользователей и ролей.